# Cryptography: Digital Signing of Virtual Good Ownership?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

Suppose we have a multi-user system whereby:

- a central authority (C) can create and issue a virtual good (Zk) to its own ownership.
- the owner (Xi) of a good (Zk) can transfer ownership to another user (Xj).
- a user (Xi) can claim to own a good (Zk), and this should be verifiable.

So for example:

1. C creates two virtual goods, Z1 and Z2. (and has never created Z3)
2. C transfers ownership of Z1 to user X1
3. X1 transfers ownership of Z1 to X2

The following claims should test true:

- X2 claims to own Z1
- C claims to own Z2

The following claims should test false:

- X2 claims to own Z2 (not owner)
- X2 claims to own Z3 (does not exist)
- X1 claims to own Z1 (former owner)

Here are the questions:

- What is a sketch of the architecture of such a system?
- What cryptographic methods do we use (digital signatures, pki, etc?) and in what arrangement?
- What keys are created and who are they given to?
- What is the algorithm C uses to create a good Zk?
- What is the algorithm Xi and Xj uses to transfer ownership?
- What algorithm does Xi use to generate a claim to own Zk?
- What algorithm does Xi use to verify a claim by Xj to own Zk?

Comment: You could look at [bitcoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) for inspiration.

Comment: OK, there are some answers, but please ask these kind of questions at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Signatures are used for verifying that a message generated by a sender was indeed generated by that sender.  In this case you could use digital signatures for verifying that the generator of the product is indeed the Central Authority.  In this case the product would ALWAYS have digital signature that was generated by the CA using there private key, then anybody could have use the CA's public key for verification.

Transference,  This is where it gets difficult. What party is going to be doing the verification.  Is it going to be the CA, or is it just so that party 2 knows that party 1 was the true (and rightful) owner prior to purchasing the item, or both?

OK, based on your comment.  I think the answer is to always have the CA in the mix.  In this case you could essentially always have the virtual good encrypted via a symmetric alforithm like AES on the owner's system until time of use.  The key to decrypt the virtual good shall never be stored (long term) on the owners system, but rather, passed down by the CA when requested.  Now the CA can hold the keys for the current valid users.  How those keys are stored or calculated I will talk about later.

For User Xj verifying that item Z1 truly belongs to User Xi, that could be as simple as the CA signing a message made up of the Owners' user ID and the encrypted copy of the item with the CA private key.  Since the User name is included in the message, when user Xj verifies the signature using the CAs public key, user Xj knows it is valid and owned by user Xi.

Setting up of keys:
The CA should obviously have an asymmetric key pair (private and public).  Each user should also have an asymmetric key pair.  The CA will share it's public key with its users, and each user will share his / her public key with the CA (this can be part of an account setup of some form).  A user will now log in to the CA by encrypting a Unique User ID encrypted and signed using the User's private key appending the public key to the message.  The CA decrypts using the public key provided (all of this could be processed within an SSL setup, or essentially a second layer of encryption to help BETTER protect the Unique IDs).  When a purchase occurs, the CA can create a key lets say by performing the HASH of the Users Unique ID, the virtual Item's serial number, and the CA's PRIVATE key to use as the symmetric algorithm's input key.  The CA now encrypts the item with this new calculated key, and signs it with their (CA) private asymmetric key.  The newly encrypted item is now sent to the users' system.  The CA doesnt have to store the key because they know how to calculate it, the CAs private key is still protected as you are taking the HASH of it plus other things, and the item is now uniquely encrypted for each user.

Now to decrypt the valid item, the user is already logged in, and the CA already know this is a valid owner of this item, so the key can be calculated and SSLed down to the user for live decrypt.  This key is never stored on the machine though.

Now if a user who DOESNT own the item tries to use a copy of the valid user's item, one of 2 things will happen, the non-owner user will log in and an incorrect key for the item will be calculated, and thus the item will decrypt improperly, of the CA can perform auto recognition that the user doesnt infact own the item and from there lock the item from all accounts, let the valid user's account know that someone is trying to use there item, etc...

Transference:
The valid user will log in and state they want to transfer the item to another user.  At this point the item is de-associated with owner 1, and re-associated to owner 2.  Since the CA owns all key generation, owner 1 will no longer be able to decrypt their item.  And indeed at the point of transference, the software could simply delete the copy on the local system of owner 1.

Sorry this is long winded, but these types of problems normally are.

Comment: Any user (Xi) of this system should be able to generate a claim of ownership over any good Z.  Any other user of the system (Xj) should be able to correctly verify that Xi's claim of ownership of Z is true or false.

Comment: I have an idea, just have not had time to post, I will get back on this :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is kind of out from classic cryptography primitives. As mentioned in detail by the other answer, you need to go with public key cryptography. Following is procedures I can think of:

The ownership of goods, say the binding of goods ID and users public key, need be tracked by authority CA, to make sure all goods are uniquely owned.

- If goods were initially created by users, user need to submit its public key and goods ID to CA for endorsement. (If goods itself is immutable, we can use cartographic hash value as goods ID, to force unique binding of goods and goods ID. Otherwise, we need to introduce additional schemes to track binding between goods and goods ID, which we'll not discuss here)
- We must rely on CA to prove ownership. User posts a public key and goods id tuple to CA, which CA returns true or false.
- To transfer ownership, owner generates a signature on the goods ID, his public key and the new owner's public key to CA. CA checks and updates its database, maybe also notifies the new owner.
- To minimize CA involvement in ownership proving, one solution is to let CA issue timed "ownership ticket" -- signature of goods id, owner public key and invalid date, so that CA need not be involved in every ownership verification process. Goods owner renew the ticket before it expires. Also goods is only transferable after it passes the invalid date.

The major role of CA is to guarantee no two users can claim a same goods, which I'll call it "double-claiming". It is very difficult to get rid of "double-claiming" vulnerability in a decentralized manner. There is a very interesting project named [bitcoin](http://bitcoin.org/) that tries to address the very similar question. It provides a novel solution to go away with CA. The [design paper](http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) covers the essential idea, if you are interested.